# Write if condition in single line

Tags: .net, vb.net, aspose

Is there a way to write the following in a single line, where the sum function only gets executed if the "InvoiceSum" field exists (and without having to repeat the InvoiceSum field)?

```
If (Doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames().ToList.Exists(Function(x) x = "InvoiceSum")) Then
  Doc.MailMerge.Execute({"InvoiceSum"}, {GetInvoiceSum()})
End If
```

The idea is to only execute the mailmerge in case the InvoiceSum exists as a field in the document, because the GetInvoiceSum function can be very expensive.

I would like to avoid having to wrap each merge field in an if condition, which pollutes the code, but also is error prone, since you have to write "InvoiceSum" twice.

Comment: *"which pollutes the code"* - How so?  By making the intent of the code clear and easily understandable?  *"also is error prone, since you have to write "InvoiceSum" twice"* - You can address that by (1) using a constant instead of repeating the value and (2) testing the code before releasing it to production.

Comment: Imagine the above example code with 200 mailmerge fields. If it would be possible to put that in a single line like ExecuteMailMergeIfFieldExists, that would be much more clear and understandable.

Comment: If you're repeating an operation many times then that sounds like an opportunity to extract that operation into its own method and call the method many times.

Comment: Can you do `Doc.MailMerge.Execute(If(Condition,DoThis,DoThat))`

Comment: If you need to call this 200 times, you should really put it in a method instead of a one liner. Then put the fields in a list and loop the list.

Comment: The one liner could indeed be a method call, but how would that method look like? How to avoid the GetInvoiceSum() method being executed if the InvoiceSum field doesn't exist?

Comment: Also, you can shorten your condition to: `Doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames().Any(Function(x) x = "InvoiceSum")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different functions for different fields, you may want to try using a dictionary to point a field to a corresponding function. Then you can filter the dictionary according to whether it has the MailMerge fields as keys. Then you only execute the function for the filtered fields.

```
' build your dictionary of [fieldname, function] somehow
Dim fieldsAndFunctions As New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Object))()
fieldsAndFunctions.Add("InvoiceSum", AddressOf GetInvoiceSum)
fieldsAndFunctions.Add("InvoiceAvg", AddressOf GetInvoiceAvg)
fieldsAndFunctions.Add("InvoiceMax", AddressOf GetInvoiceMax)

' get the field names once
Dim existingFields = doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames()

' filter your dictionary down to only the items whose field names are in your MailMerge object
Dim filteredFieldsAndFunctions = fieldsAndFunctions.
    Where(Function(kvp) existingFields.Contains(kvp.Key))

' call execute, passing the fields and values as arrays
If filteredFieldsAndFunctions.Any() Then
    doc.MailMerge.Execute(
        filteredFieldsAndFunctions.Select(Function(f) f.Key).ToArray(),
        filteredFieldsAndFunctions.Select(Function(f) f.Value()).ToArray())
End If
```

The values are calculated at the end only for fields which exist. Note the `()` shorthand for `Func.Invoke()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are performing this multiple times, then maybe store the result of Doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames() rather than calling it each time.

According to the documentation I found, Doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames() returns an array of string.  If so, try this:

```
Dim FieldNames As String() = Doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames()
If FieldNames.Contains("InvoiceSum") Then Doc.MailMerge.Execute({"InvoiceSum"}, {GetInvoiceSum()})
```

or if you want to create a method, try this:

```
Private Sub MergeIfExists(FieldName As String, FieldNames As String(), Action As Action)
    If FieldNames.Contains(FieldName) Then Doc.MailMerge.Execute({FieldName}, {Action})
End Sub
```

usage:

```
Dim FieldNames As String() = Doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames()
MergeIfExists("InvoiceSum", FieldNames, AddressOf GetInvoiceSum)
```

Maybe better to pass Doc to the method too, but I wasn't sure of the type so will leave that to you.

Comment: I think `Action` should be `Func(Of Object)`, and Execute takes an array of Object as the second argument so the delegate should be invoked there. Try `{action()}` as the second argument.

Comment: @djv - thanks. I didn't have access to MailMerge to test it so relied on copying the code from original post. Happy to stand corrected.